# Unable to insert values into a list at the correct index

Tags: python, list, sorting, insertion

I receive a list of numbers and I want to sort them. 
the input looks like this:

```
i:1,3,5,8
n:2
t:4,7
a:6
v:9
```

and comes in form of a txt file.

The code looks like this:

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in decks for item in sublist]
p = [] 

for x in range(len(flat_list)):
    nr = flat_list[x][0]
    o = nr -1
    p.insert((o),(flat_list[x][1]))

print(p)
```

which gives this output:

```
[(1, 'i'), (2, 'n'), (3, 'i'), (4, 't'), (5, 'i'), (6, 'a'), (8, 'i'), (7, 
 't'), (9, 'v')]
```

which is almost what I want, it except for 7 and 8.
so what do I do wrong ?

Comment: @timgeb The question is clear no? They want to know why their code doesn't result in a sorted output. However, they should show the original input, show us `decks`

Comment: I don't think you understand what `p = []*(len(flat_list)-1) ` is doing.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Kind of. I employed some snark because the question OP seems to be asking is unanswerable as he did not provide any context about his data structures.

Comment: @timgeb Well they only joined SO today, and they've edited it now, be nice don't forget :)

Answer (score 1):

You declare an empty list:

```
p = []
```

But you call `list.insert` on it. This, unfortunately, leads to some unintended side effects. Observe:

```
In [209]: p.insert(999, 0)

In [210]: p
Out[210]: [0]
```

Which is inserted at the 0<sup>th</sup> position, despite the fact that you wanted it in the (999 + 1)<sup>th</sup> place. This sort of thing is the reason you see items in the wrong place, they were never inserted properly to begin with.

---

The fix would be to multiply a `[None]` list. Also, you should be able to simplify your insertion logic drastically, if you iterate over the elements rather than their indices.

```
p = [None] * len(flat_list) 

for i, y in flat_list: 
    p[i - 1] = y
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really work on phrasing your questions.

But I believe this might be the answer you're looking for.

```
from operator import itemgetter
flat_list = [(1,a),(6,b),(3,d),(7,c),(9,a),(4,b)]
sorted(flat_list, key=itemgetter(0))
```

I found this by googling a little, maybe you should try the same.

Comment: `itemgetter` does nothing here, it's the same as `sorted(flat_list)`. Anyway, you're not taking their initial input as a starting point

Comment: I see, thanks for telling me that. I'm not very experienced, but I wanted to see if I could answer some of the questions here.

Comment: Only answer questions, when you *know* the answer :)